# Install LuCI on ubuntu instead of OpenWRT

Tags: ubuntu, openwrt, luci

I have a Linux board with Ubuntu Trusty on it - this board has WiFi, ethernet port and GPRS modem as well. In addition to my application running on it, I am looking to install LuCI on it so that I can use that Linux board as a router and use LuCI as a GUI for that router. What are the dependencies of LuCI?

Are there any other alternatives to LuCI that I can try that as well? I see Gargoyle-router but I'm unclear on how to install on Ubuntu as well.

Comment: This guy has LuCI running on Ubuntu: https://mondwan.blogspot.co.uk/2015/06/how-to-setup-luci-web-framework-with.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt that LuCI will work on anything but OpenWRT - it is designed to work with the OpenWRT configuration, scripts, etc. I'd imagine it would be the same for Gargoyle's web interface.

One alternative is [WiFiAdmin](http://wifiadmin.sourceforge.net), which seems like it should work. You could also use something like [WebMin](http://www.webmin.com).

Another option, of course, is installing OpenWRT instead of Ubuntu - it runs on x86 hardware (I'm assuming here you have an x86 system) and will give you the ability to use LuCI and to treat your system as an appliance.

Comment: Thanks @mjturner I installed WebMin its good for Administartors but not a  UI like router, it needs more skills and efforts to configure interfaces. I will check WiFiAdmin now.

Comment: WiFiAdmin doesn't have the port forwarding and other Firewall features.

Comment: @A1-C Another option is to use OpenWRT instead of Ubuntu - I've added that to my answer now

Comment: thanks, Actually its a ARM board 

i.MX6 Quad-Core ARM® Cortex A9 processor at 1GHz

I have installed the x86 in my VMBOX and also used openwrt on some of my routers. only issue is I don't know how to port it on my hardware.

Comment: @A1-C OpenWRT [already supports](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/hardware/soc/soc.freescale.imx) the i.MX6. Here are download links: [15.02 RC2](http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05-rc2/imx6/generic/) and [trunk](http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05-rc2/imx6/generic/). Obviously, check documentation before installing it!

Comment: Wow that's Great I will check and get back. May do it next week.

Comment: I've tried WebMin and it is awsum. I agree that it is a bit complicated but if you are basic skills with networking its an easy game. I had to switch from to OpenWRT to Ubuntu because there is bad array support of OpenWRT.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

https://github.com/lisaac/luci-in-docker

It's base on luci 21.02, but it's luci UI only, there's no ubus, no rpcd,
use for manager uci config and execute command/script.